# @ManyToOne, foreign key or both?

Tags: database, spring, jpa

This can be a duplicated question, or a very basic one, but I need some help...

So I am building an application using spring boot, I have students and classes many students can be in one class so this is a many to one. This what I did:

```
@Entity 
@Data 
public class Eleve implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int idEt;
private String nomEt;
private String prenomEt;
@Column(length=1)
private String sexe;
private Date dobEt;
private String adresseEt;
private String telEt;
private String parentName;
private Date dateInscription;
private Date dateSortie;

@ManyToOne
private Classe classe;
```

}

This is working and I see the `classe_id_cl` in eleve table but it is NOT a foreign_key! This column can accept any value.

**UPDATE**
Btw, this is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-boot-edss
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.session.store-type=none
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Do I need to use something like flywayDB and force it to be a foreign_key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the join column on your ManyToOne mapping:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "columnname")
private Classe classe;
```

**Update**

Ok, according to your application.properties, you are using a dialect which does not support foreign key constrainst.

The proper configuration would be:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: so you are referring to the auto schema creation during startup?

Comment: yes for the moment, `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: have you added @OneToMany mapping on the Classe entity?

Comment: I'm just specifying one way. I mean only in the Etudiant entity

Comment: i see so its unidiretional.. can you add all your application.properties?

Comment: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-boot-edss

spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.session.store-type=none

spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Try to change to this dialect.. org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: Ok lets make the post right now... please add the properties to the question and i will update the answer. So that other users can benefit from it. The wrong properties.. so that its clear whats wrong